# Build a CMS given the data, certificates and pre-generated signature

Tags: openssl, signature, pkcs#7

I have a third-party web server that is fed a username, a password, and the SHA-256 hash of a message to sign on behalf of that username. It returns the signature and the certificate chain in two separate messages. The certificate is X.509 and the signature is, I assume, raw bytes, not any ASN.1 form.

Is there a way to combine these into a proper CMS structure as defined in PKCS#7? I cannot do that in Windows (No MSG API takes raw bytes to build a CMS) but I hope that OpenSSL can combine them successfully.

I must embed this signature into PDF which I can do if it was `CryptMsgUpdate` in windows that did the signing (a full CMS structure would be returned).

I *could* study the PKCS#7 structure and use an ASN1 compiler but I was hoping there's an easier way.

Comment: It's an interesting question. First I thought that the signature must be over some structure containing a hash of the data, but it seems you can actually take a signature over the data as well. Then I thought oh, maybe you can extend the `CmsSigner` class, but that's a sealed class so no hope there either. I'm still wondering though that if you can insert a HSM into the signing process - something that I know that has been done - then you should also be able to insert a signature generation device that simply maps a hash to an existing signature.

Comment: Yep, I'd probably go for implementing a CSP for .NET and simply return the generated signature. Again, we don't know how the signature is returned. RSA is usually raw bytes but ANSI compatible ECDSA might be encoded using DER. It usually doesn't matter as long as the signature format is what the verifier expects. For CMS I would strongly expect ANSI compatible ECDSA signatures, for instance.

Comment: I can implement a CNG provider but I dont know exactly what the CNG router supports.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't want to have signed attributes, what you want is possible.  But once you have signed attributes then the data that is input into the RSA (or whatever) signature algorithm is different than just the basic data('s hash).

While there may be API to do it more directly (for example, OpenSSL probably lets you work directly with SignedData and SignerInfo types), the following example code (C#, using System.Formats.Asn1) shows that it's possible to create a PKCS#7 document from just the inputs you have.  Because of the .NET SignedData class's design, you can't *verify* the signature without the original data (not just its hash), but that's fine... I know what it is in this sample :).

This sample was built modelled on [IETF RFC 2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315). Something newer (e.g. RFC 5652) could be used, which would allow the SubjectKeyIdentifier-based certificate association... but remember that signedAttrs cannot be used... or you'll need to recompute the RSA signature.

```cs
X509Certificate2 certificate;
byte[] hash = SHA256.HashData(ReadOnlySpan<byte>.Empty);
byte[] signature;

using (RSA key = RSA.Create(3072))
{
    signature = key.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    
    CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest(
        "CN=Test",
        key,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    certificate = req.CreateSelfSigned(
        now.AddMinutes(-5),
        now.AddMinutes(5));
}

// The order doesn't matter in this collection, since the encoded PKCS#7
// will (if DER-encoded) order them from smallest encoding to largest)
X509Certificate2[] allCertificates = new[] { certificate };
byte[] pkcs7;

using (certificate)
{
    AsnWriter writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    Asn1Tag context0 = new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0);

    // ContentInfo
    using (writer.PushSequence())
    {
        // contentType = id-signedData
        writer.WriteObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.7.2");

        // content
        using (writer.PushSequence(context0))
        {
            // SignedData
            using (writer.PushSequence())
            {
                // version: 1
                writer.WriteInteger(1);

                // digestAlgorithms
                using (writer.PushSetOf())
                {
                    // AlgorithmIdentifier (SHA-2-256)
                    using (writer.PushSequence())
                    {
                        writer.WriteObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
                    }
                }

                // contentInfo
                using (writer.PushSequence())
                {
                    // contentType = id-data
                    writer.WriteObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1");

                    // since we don't have the original data, omit the content
                }

                // certificates
                using (writer.PushSetOf(context0))
                {
                    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in allCertificates)
                    {
                        // X.509 certificates are written down with no special extra ceremony
                        writer.WriteEncodedValue(cert.RawData);
                    }
                }

                // no crls to encode

                // signerInfos
                using (writer.PushSetOf())
                {
                    // SignerInfo
                    using (writer.PushSequence())
                    {
                        // version: 1
                        writer.WriteInteger(1);

                        // issuerAndSerialNumber
                        using (writer.PushSequence())
                        {
                            // issuer, an encoded X.500 Distinguished Name
                            writer.WriteEncodedValue(certificate.IssuerName.RawData);

                            // serialNumber
                            writer.WriteInteger(certificate.SerialNumberBytes.Span);
                        }

                        // digestAlgorithm: AlgorithmIdentifier (SHA-2-256)
                        using (writer.PushSequence())
                        {
                            writer.WriteObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
                        }

                        // no authenticatedAttributes

                        // digestEncryptionAlgorithm,
                        // which really means signature-envelope algorithm
                        // AlgorithmIdentifier(RSA, NULL)
                        using (writer.PushSequence())
                        {
                            writer.WriteObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1");
                            writer.WriteNull();
                        }

                        // encryptedDigest, aka signature
                        writer.WriteOctetString(signature);

                        // no un-authenticated attributes, either
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pkcs7 = writer.Encode();
}

SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(Array.Empty<byte>()), detached: true);
signedCms.Decode(pkcs7);

try
{
    signedCms.CheckSignature(true);
    Console.WriteLine("Signature check succeeded");
}
catch (CryptographicException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Signature check failed");
}
```